# I would like to display numbers in a certain way but it's off-centre

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, iteration

I want to display number in rows, where the number of rows is asked as user input and the number of columns is always 4. It all works fine but it's off-centre. This is my code:

```
public class Practise {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        int number = scanner.nextInt();
        number = number * 4;
        
        char[] array = new char[number];

        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            System.out.print("  " + (i)+" :");
            if(array[i]==0) System.out.print("- ");
            if((i+1)%4==0) System.out.println();       
        }
    }
}
```

So if the user enters 5 rows, the output is below. When it hits the double digits it goes off-centre.

```
 0 :-   1 :-   2 :-   3 :- 
  4 :-   5 :-   6 :-   7 :- 
  8 :-   9 :-   10 :-   11 :- 
  12 :-   13 :-   14 :-   15 :- 
  16 :-   17 :-   18 :-   19 :-
```

I want the output to be like below so the colons match up. Any ideas how to get it like this? I tried playing around with the code where if i>9 then do something but it just messed it up even more. Thank you!!

```
   0 :-   1 :-   2 :-   3 :- 
   4 :-   5 :-   6 :-   7 :- 
   8 :-   9 :-  10 :-  11 :- 
  12 :-  13 :-  14 :-  15 :- 
  16 :-  17 :-  18 :-  19 :-
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%4d :", i);
    if(array[i]==0) System.out.print("- ");
    if((i+1)%4==0) System.out.println();
}
```

output for `number = 5`:

```
   0 :-    1 :-    2 :-    3 :- 
   4 :-    5 :-    6 :-    7 :- 
   8 :-    9 :-   10 :-   11 :- 
  12 :-   13 :-   14 :-   15 :- 
  16 :-   17 :-   18 :-   19 :-
```